# Access violation reading location 0x00000000. with argv[]

Tags: c, pointers, access-violation, argv, strcmp

I am running the following program and got errors:

```
First-chance exception at 0x0f32d440 (msvcr100d.dll) in c.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x772815de in c.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
The program '[9048] c.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

Here is the code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[]) //char *argv[] 
{ 
int i; 

printf("These are the %d command- line arguments passed to main:\n\n", argc); 
if(strcmp(argv[1],"123")==0)                
    {
        printf("success\n");
     }
else
for(i=0; i<=argc; i++) 
    //if(strcmp(argv[1],"abc")==0)

    printf("argv[%d]:%s\n", i, argv[i]);
/*printf("\nThe environment string(s)on this system are:\n\n"); 
for(i=0; env[i]!=NULL; i++) 
printf(" env[%d]:%s\n", i, env[i]);*/ 
system("pause");
}
```

The problem should be with the strcmp function but I dont know how to solve it.
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have (at least) two problems.

The first is doing this:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1],"123")==0)
```

without first checking that `argc >= 2`.

The second is this:

```
for(i=0; i<=argc; i++)
```

in that you *should* be processing arguments `0` thru `argc - 1` inclusive. What that loop does is process arguments `0` through `argc` and `argv[argc]` is always `NULL`.

The following program illustrates one way to fix this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    printf ("These are the %d command-line argument(s) passed to main:\n", argc);
    if ((argc >= 2) && (strcmp (argv[1], "123") == 0)) {
        printf ("   success\n");
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)  {
            printf ("   argv[%d] = [%s]\n", i, argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can see that the comparison with `"123"` is only done after ensuring that `argv[1]` is populated correctly. In addition, the loop has been changed to exclude `argv[argc]` since that's not one of the arguments. A transcript follows:

```
pax> testprog
These are the 1 command-line argument(s) passed to main:
   argv[0] = [testprog]

pax> testprog 123
These are the 2 command-line argument(s) passed to main:
   success

pax> testprog a b c
These are the 4 command-line argument(s) passed to main:
   argv[0] = [testprog]
   argv[1] = [a]
   argv[2] = [b]
   argv[3] = [c]
```

Answer (score 1):

`for(i=0; i<=argc; i++)` should be `for(i=0; i<argc; i++)`.

C/C++ arrays are 0 to n-1. You are running 1 spot off the end of the array.

Comment: Also make sure that in your second array argv there is actually more than 1 item you are currently referencing the second item in the array at argv[1], should probably be argv[0]